# How to access XML POST request with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, xmlhttprequest

I making a web app with node.js.I have a API on /api/users/register that takes name and password.I want to sent a POST request to that adress with XMLHttpRequest.The request comes to the API but i cant figure out how to access name and password.
I tried to access with req.body but it returns an empty list.Is there any other method for accessing data?

Heres my XML request file

```
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn')

function registerUser() {
    const name = document.getElementById('name')
    const password = document.getElementById('password')
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('POST', '/api/users/register')
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({name:name.value, password:password.value}))
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', registerUser)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing a string to `send()`, XHR is going to set a `Content-Type: text/plain` request header by default. The first thing you need to do is override that.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

The in the server-side code you haven't shared with us, you need to read the request body, parse it as JSON, and (assuming you want to read it from `req.body`) assign it to `req.body`.

Assuming you are using Express.js, see [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) which says:

> req.body
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

So:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/some-path', (req, res) => {
    const { name, password } = req.body;
    console.log(name, password);
    res.send("some response");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```